# How to get value from appsettings.json in Program class in asp.net core console application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Could you please tell me how to get the value from an appsettings.json in the "Program.cs". If I start at the "Startup.cs" like this:

**Model**

```
class AppConfiguration
    {
        public string UrlProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddSingleton(Configuration.GetSection("Url").Get<AppConfiguration>());
```

Then go to the "Program.cs" and code it like so:

**Program.cs**

```
public static string Url { get; set; }
public static AppConfiguration configurtion { get; set; }

public Program(AppConfiguration configuration)
{
    Url = configuration.ToString();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Run();
}

public static IWebHost CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
     WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
     .UseStartup<Startup>()
     .UseKestrel((hostingContext, options) =>
     {
         var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(Url); // ERROR HERE
             options.Listen(ipAddress, 9001);
     }).Build();
```

I would have an error since the `main` gets executed first then the `CreateWebHostBuilder` so the `Url` will not get filled in first. But if I use this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                   .AddSingleton(Configuration.GetSection("Url").Get<AppConfiguration>());
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Run();
        }
```

The `Configuration.GetSection("Url")` is not recognized. How do I get the value from an appsettings.json in the Program.Main?

### Update

as per "Tan" I made the necessary edits to my `Program.cs`. I think I am near solving it. It's just that the "Url" is still null when it loads. Please see my edit:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = CreateWebHostBuilder(args);
            builder.ConfigureLogging((context, builder) =>
            {
                Url = context.Configuration["ApplicationUrl"];
            }).Build().Run();
        }

       
        public static IHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
           Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
           {
               webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
               .UseKestrel((hostingContext, options) =>
               {
                   var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(Url);
                   options.Listen(ipAddress, 9001);
                   options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null;
               });
           });
```

Please see the screenshot:

[image]

This is the **appsettings.json**

```
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AcceptedOrigin": [ "http://localhost:4200" ],
  "ApplicationUrl":  "192.168.1.4"
}
```

### Update 2

This is the **appsettings.json**

```
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AcceptedOrigin": [ "http://localhost:4200" ],
  "ApplicationUrl":  "192.168.1.4"
}
```

static void Main(string[] args)
{

```
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
   Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
   .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
   {
       webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
       .UseKestrel((context, options) =>
       {
           options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null;

            // "192.168.1.4"
            string url = context.Configuration["Url"];
           var ipAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(url);
       });
   });
```

This is what I get in the `Startup.cs`:

[image]

In the `Program.cs`:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the file `appsettings.json`, you can define `Url` property like this:

```
{
  "Url": "https://example.com"
}
```

In the file `Program.cs`, inside `Main` method, you can access that property via `ConfigureLogging` extension method:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = CreateHostBuilder(args);

        builder.ConfigureLogging((context, builder) => {
            // "https://example.com"
            string url = context.Configuration["Url"];

            // do stuff...
        }).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseKestrel(options =>
            {
                options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null;
            });
        });
}
```

---

**Update:**

If you want to get the property value via `UseKestrel` extension method, you can assign it directly, no need to store in the field.

Because you will lose that value when the extension method finish *(`Url` will become `null` outside the extension method)*

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseKestrel((context, options) =>
            {
                options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null;

                // "192.168.1.4"
                string url = context.Configuration["Url"];
                var ipAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(url);
            });
        });
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: 1]

Comment: Sir, I made the necessary updates. I think it is almost there. But the problem is, the string Url still comes out null. Can you please help some more? Thank you. Please see my edit above.

Comment: @Ibanez1408 I've updated my answer. You can try again.

Comment: Sir, for some reason, "Url" property in the appsettings.json is not found. Did I create the appsettings.json correctly? Even on my Startup, I get null when I try to access it. Please see the update.

Comment: @Ibanez1408 That's because in your `appsettings.json`, you had replaced `Url` (in my example) with `ApplicationUrl`. Try again with `context.Configuration["ApplicationUrl"];`

Comment: I got it Sir. I just need to set my appsettings.json's property to "CopyToOutputDirectory" to "Copy if Newer". Thank you very very very VERY MUCH!